# Preserving type information in akka Receive

Tags: scala, reflection, akka

Is it possible to preserve type information in message handler partial function?

I have partial function eventHandler that matches event by some specific parameters:

```
  def eventHandler: Receive = {
    case event: Event ⇒
        ...
        val matchingReactions = projectConfiguration.reactions.filter(reaction ⇒ reaction.eventSelector.matches(event))
```

Where matches method validates event against a set of rules through reflection:

```
case class EventSelector(ops: List[FieldEventSelectorOp]) {
  def matches[T <: Event](event: T)(implicit tag: ru.TypeTag[T], classtag: ClassTag[T]): Boolean = {
    ops.map {
      op ⇒ op.matches(event)
    }.reduceLeft(_ & _)
  }
}

case class FieldEventSelectorOp(field: String, operation: Symbol, value: Any) { 
  def matches[T <: Event](event: T)(implicit tag: ru.TypeTag[T], classtag: ClassTag[T]): Boolean = {
...
}
```

So, when I check what is the TypeTag in matches method it returns just Event, not subclass of event - how do I make it pass full type information?

Update:

case class hierarchy for events:

```
trait Event {
  def eventType: String
  def eventName: String = this.getClass.getSimpleName
}

trait VCSEvent extends Event {
  def eventType: String = "VCS"
}

case class BranchAdded(branch: String) extends VCSEvent
case class TagAdded(tag: String, commitId: String) extends VCSEvent
```

Concrete matcher:

```
case class FieldEventSelectorOp(field: String, operation: Symbol, value: Any) extends EventSelectorOp {
  def matches[T <: Event](event: T)(implicit tag: ru.TypeTag[T], classtag: ClassTag[T]): Boolean = {
    val mirror = ru.runtimeMirror(event.getClass.getClassLoader)
    val memberSymbol = tag.tpe.member(ru.newTermName(field))

    if (memberSymbol.name.decoded.equals("<none>"))
      return false

    val fieldValue = if (memberSymbol.isMethod) {
      mirror.reflect(event).reflectMethod(memberSymbol.asMethod).apply()
    } else {
      mirror.reflect(event).reflectField(memberSymbol.asTerm).get
    }

    operation match {
      case 'eq ⇒ fieldValue.equals(value)
      case _   ⇒ false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the definition of Event and also maybe a couple of example Event classes?  My suspicion is that you don't need all that Type/Class Tag stuff and could instead just use getClass but I need to understand your Event model first.

Comment: Updated. I think i may be able to use getClass, although have to validate it, but still generic question on preserving type information is valid

Comment: Solution through getClass worked, indeed, though the generic question is still open. Summoning @ViktorKlang

Comment: I think you're going to have to frame this in such a way that you show that generics are needed or else you're going to have a difficult time getting an answer.  With this particular example it's not needed and working with akka for a while, I have not run into the need for this functionality.

Comment: You'll have to embed the TypeTag or ClassTag within the event at creation time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TypeTags describe types which exist only at compile time: at runtime the types are erased, all you get is available via `event.getClass`. If you want to pass generic type information into the actor, then there is exactly one way to do it: within the message.

```
trait Event[T] {
  def typeTag: ru.TypeTag[T]
  ...
}

case class MyEvent[T](...)(implicit val typeTag: ru.TypeTag[T])
```

Comment: Can you, please, describe in a bit more detail how I should/can get the typeTag when processing received message? I suppose it is needed to provide somehow the information about TypeTag when instantiating the case class, am I right? Thanks

Comment: The documentation is very helpful: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html (first hit on google for "scala typetag" BTW).

Comment: I've read everything from the link you provided even before I have posted the question above but I'm still unclear what to do in receive method. If I try this:
`case m: Message[_] => {val temp = new MyGenericClass[m.typeTag.tpe]()}`
I got the complaint from compiler: `type typeTag is not a member of Message[_]`
Basically, I understand why, but I'm not sure what to put instead of `_` in that case statement.

Comment: In the meantime I changed pattern matching to constructor matching: `case m@Message(payload) => {...}`. When I print the m.typeTag.tpe I get the correct type, but I'm not able to do much with that typeTag besides printing it out. Been looking over the various articles, discussions and conclusions and everything I've found out is that I should probably use ClassTag for this kind of stuff and not TypeTag. Any help or hint would be very appreciated.

Comment: You can do all type calculations that you might need once you hold `m.typeTag.tpe` in hand; you can check whether it is a subtype of some type that you know by using `<:<` etc. The question is: why do you think that you need this in the first place? The last comment makes me wonder whether you may have jumped towards a (broken) solution without clearly formulating the problem first.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. What I need to do here is the following (payload is of type `T`): `case m@Message(payload) => { new MyClass[m.typeTag.tpe]}`. But, this is not possible since the compiler sees `T` as `Any`. One solution is to put some generator function within case class and instantiate a new class in within case class itself (with typeTag provided since within that case class type is T, not Any), but that defeats the purpose of case class to be as lightweight as possible.

Comment: Please open a separate question with appropriate code, from what I can tell you will not need TypeTags.

Comment: @htomek See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40578024/preserving-type-arguments-in-akka-receive