# Preserving type arguments in Akka receive

Tags: scala, akka, type-erasure, scala-reflect

This question has kind of been answered by Roland Kuhn in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819924/preserving-type-information-in-akka-receive), however, despite several comments asking for detail, he didn't bother to share the complete answer.

Here's what I want to do: I have a wrapper class `case class Event[T](t: T)` of which I send instances to an Akka actor. In the `receive` method of that actor, I then want to distinguish between `Event[Int]` and `Event[String]`, which obviously isn't so simple due to type erasure.

What Roland Kuhn shares in the mentioned post is that "there is exactly one way to do it", that is, embodying the type information within the message. So I did this:

```
case class Event[T](t: T)(implicit val ct: ClassTag[T])
```

Even though asked by different people to provide it, Roland Kuhn does not say what to actually do within the `receive` method then. Here's what I tried.

```
def receive = {
  case e: Event =>
    if (e.ct.runtimeClass == classOf[Int])
      println("Got an Event[Int]!")
    else if (e.ct.runtimeClass == classOf[String])
      println("Got an Event[String]!")
    else
      println("Got some other Event!")
  case _ =>
    println("Got no Event at all!")
}
```

This is the best I could come up with as it's hard to wrap one's head around Scala's reflection jungle. It's not compiling, though:

```
value ct is not a member of Any
else if (e.ct.runtimeClass == classOf[String])
           ^
```

Thus, I am asking specifically about what the `receive` method should look like.

Comment: This looks right to me (except it's simpler to compare `ClassTag` directly: `e.ct == ClassTag.Int` and `e.ct == classTag[String]`). In the error message you have `s.ct` which isn't in the code.

Comment: Changed it to `e.ct`. I simplified the code above to be self-contained in this post. The error message I copy-pasted from the real code, though. Good catch, thank you!

Comment: You also need to fix `case e: Event[_]`. After this, it compiles: http://scastie.org/23724.

Comment: Post it as an answer! Maybe you could elaborate on how to use the shorthand notation `Event[T : ClassTag]` in this case. Also, what would be the `String` version of `ClassTag.Int`? Thank you so much, Alexey!

Comment: Posted. You can't use `T: ClassTag` in this case (well, you can, but it ends up more verbose). `classTag[String]` _is_ the `String` version of `ClassTag.Int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing the error `Event takes type parameters`:

```
def receive = {
  case e: Event[_] =>
    if (e.ct.runtimeClass == classOf[Int])
      println("Got an Event[Int]!")
    else if (e.ct.runtimeClass == classOf[String])
      println("Got an Event[String]!")
    else
      println("Got some other Event!")
  case _ =>
    println("Got no Event at all!")
}
```

the code compiles. It can be slightly simplified by not looking inside the `ClassTag`s (of course, the implementation of `ClassTag#equals` is going to compare the classes):

```
import scala.reflect.{ClassTag, classTag}

def receive = {
  case e: Event[_] =>
    if (e.ct == ClassTag.Int) // or classTag[Int]
      println("Got an Event[Int]!")
    else if (e.ct == classTag[String])
      println("Got an Event[String]!")
    else
      println("Got some other Event!")
  case _ =>
    println("Got no Event at all!")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do pattern matching on the internal variable inside a nested class in which case it is more concise, you can utilise various pattern matching tricks and you don't even need ClassTag: eg

```
case class Event[T](t: T)    

def receive = {
  case Event(t: Int) => 
    println("Int")
  case Event((_: Float | _: Double)) => 
    println("Floating Point")
  case Event(_) =>
    println("Other")
}
```